# Appending data frames in R based on column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I am relatively new to R, so bear with me.  I have a list of data frames that I need to combine into one data frame.  so:

```
  dfList <- list(
    df1 = data.frame(x=letters[1:2],y=1:2),
    df2 = data.frame(x=letters[3:4],z=3:4)
  )
```

comes out as:

```
$df1   
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 2

$df2
  x z
1 c 3
2 d 4
```

and I want them to combine common columns and add anything not already there.  the result would be:

```
final result
  x y z
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c   3
4 d   4
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, it's pretty easy, actually:

```
library(dplyr)
df_merged <- bind_rows(dfList)
df_merged

  x  y  z
1 a  1 NA
2 b  2 NA
3 c NA  3
4 d NA  4
```

And if you don't want `NA` in the empty cells, you can replace them like this:

```
df_merged[is.na(df_merged)] <- 0  # or whatever you want to replace NA with
```

Comment: I knew I was overthinking it and trying too hard.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just using `do.call` with `rbind.fill`

```
do.call(rbind.fill,dfList)
  x  y  z
1 a  1 NA
2 b  2 NA
3 c NA  3
4 d NA  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with `base` function `merge()`:

```
merge(dfList$df1, dfList$df2, by = "x", all = TRUE)
#   x  y  z
# 1 a  1 NA
# 2 b  2 NA
# 3 c NA  3
# 4 d NA  4
```

Or with `dplyr` package with function `full_join`:

```
dplyr::full_join(dfList$df1, dfList$df2, by = "x")
#   x  y  z
# 1 a  1 NA
# 2 b  2 NA
# 3 c NA  3
# 4 d NA  4
```

They both join everything that is in both data.frames.

Hope that works for you.